# Weka Explorer isn't working

Tags: weka

I am using Weka Explorer to do a SMOTE oversampling of my training data. The file format is libsvm compatible. It's loaded. Everything looks fine. But when I select filter->supervised learning->SMOTE, and choose the default settings. Then I should press "apply" to start sampling, but the problem is that the "apply" button is gray, disabled. I can't do it.

What might cause this? Really thanks for any information.

The data format I loaded in Weka Exlporer is this:

-1 1:-1.0 2:-1.0 3:-1.0 4:-1.0 5:-1.0 6:-1.0 7:0.5 8:0.0043 9:0.0063 10:1.0 
1 1:-1.0 2:-1.0 3:1.0 4:-1.0 5:-1.0 6:1.0 7:0.5 8:0.0028 9:0.0028 10:3.0

This is the format LIBSVM accepts. Wekta allows libsvm format. Right?

Comment: Give us your arff file's header section, especially your class definition.

Comment: Hi, Atilla, this is my data format working with LIBSVM: -1 1:-1.0 2:-1.0 3:-1.0 4:-1.0 5:-1.0 6:-1.0 7:0.5 8:0.0043 9:0.0063 10:1.0 
1 1:-1.0 2:-1.0 3:1.0 4:-1.0 5:-1.0 6:1.0 7:0.5 8:0.0028 9:0.0028 10:3.0